# Typecasting Arraylist

Tags: java, list, generics, synchronized

I have a class which extends an Arraylist of generic type:

```
class ListA extends ArrayList<A>{

}
```

Now i create an object of `ListA` and then i want to make it a synchronized list

```
ListA a = new ListA();
a = (ListA) Collections.synchronizedList(a);
```

But above code gives typecast exception. The last thing i want to iterate over object `a` and store list memebers in a different synchronized list.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: Why do you need `a` to be a `ListA` instead of a `List<A>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obtain a customized synchronizedList in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598808/how-to-obtain-a-customized-synchronizedlist-in-java)

Comment: @PaulBellora: It is a legacy class used everywhere in my project and i  want to stick to same class.

Comment: Then that's the real issue. You should [program to an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace a class inheriting from `ArrayList<A>` with an interface and a class *containing* the list:

```
interface ListA extends List<A> {
    // Put additional methods here
}
class ListAImpl implements ListA {
    private List<A> content;
    public ListAImpl(List<A> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    // Use delegation for all methods of the List<A> interface, calling through
    // to the content list.
}
```

Now the synchronization of your `ListA` object depends on what you pass to its constructor: pass a "plain" `ArrayList<A>` to have a non-synchronized `ListA`, or pass a synchronized one to have a synchronized `ListA`.

Now your code snippet when you make a synchronized `ListA` from a non-synchronized one like this:

```
ListA a = new ListAImpl(new ArrayList<A>());
ListA sync = new ListAImpl(Collections.synchronizedList(a));
```

Comment: I think you mean `new ListAImpl`, though I don't see the point of the nested `ListA`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes - I added a comment in the code to indicate that's what's going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Collections.synchronizedList()` is declared as follows

```
public static <T> List<T> synchronizedList(List<T> list) {
```

In other words, it returns a `List`. You don't and shouldn't know anything about the implementing class. As such, you cannot expect it to be of type `ListA`.

[Program to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) whenever you can.